# Failing to insert into SQL-table from java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to update a table in mysql from a java program. 
I've successfully tried the connection by running a SELECT-query.

With the following code, I do not get any exceptions and the program isn't crashing. But the table isn't updated after running the insert-method.

```
public void insert() throws SQLException, ParseException {

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Connection con = null;

    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Write name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Write date: ");
    String dateString = in.nextLine();

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date myDate = formatter.parse(dateString);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());


    // Set the SQL statement into the query variable
    String query = "INSERT INTO Kopers (name, date) VALUES (?, ?)";



    try {
        con = connect();


        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        stmt.setString(1, name);
        stmt.setDate(2, sqlDate);


        // Execute the SQL statement that is prepared in the variable stmt
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Inserting " + name + " with date: " + sqlDate + " into database.");


    } finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Connection closed.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("Error message: " + e + "\n");
    }
    }

}
```

connect() method:

```
 public Connection connect()
{
    try
    {
        // register the driver with DriverManager
        Class.forName(driver);
        //create a connection to the database
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        // Set the auto commit of the connection to false.
        // An explicit commit will be required in order to accept
        // any changes done to the DB through this connection.
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        return con;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Try to post your connect() method

Comment: You should use try-with-resources, so you won't have to call `close()` yourself, and hence not have to catch their exceptions.

Comment: I've edited the original post and pasted the connect() method

Comment: here's the main issue `con.setAutoCommit(false);`, call `commit()` yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly commit connection using `commit()` method on Connection

i.e

```
con.commit()
```

As you have set `autoCommit(false)` in your `connect()` method

Comment: Only if the `connect()` call turned auto-commit off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've set the connection to autoCommit(false)

Comment: @Andreas yes . I should have mentioned that in answer.. Thanks

Comment: auto commit is default in jdbc

Comment: @K.Brosto so you have to `commit` the connection as you have set `autoCommit(false)`

Comment: @K.Brosto If you explicitly set `autoCommit(false)`, then you know you have to `commit()` yourself, so why is this even a question? Heck, the comment in your `connect()` method even says so!!